# Sum of rows in dataframe with same value using pandas and numpy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
       age    sex  year  population
0        0    men  1860       60589
1        0  women  1860       58837
2        1    men  1860       56001
3        1  women  1860       54833
4        2    men  1860       52502
...    ...    ...   ...         ...
35989   12  women  2022       62893a
35990   13    men  2022       64985
35991   13  women  2022       61270
35992   14    men  2022       64577
35993   14  women  2022       60611
```

I want to sum all populations with the same year for some specific age, in a list.

Example: population of everyone from 0-14 years, for all years from 1860 to 2022.

Output should be something like this:

```
Population_of_age_0_14 = [xxxxxxx, xxxxxxx, xxxxxxx, xxxxxxx...]
```

where xxxxxxx is the population and the indexes is the unique years. So first element in this list is the sum of population for everyone from age 0-14 in year 1860.

I have a solution that uses for loops. But I'm pretty sure I can utilize NumPy and Pandas to make it a lot better.

This is what I've come up with:

```
children = new_df[new_df["age"] < 15] # DataFrame with all children from 0 to 14

years = new_df["year"].unique() # List of all years from 1860 to 2022

children_population = []

for year in years: # Adding all the populations for wanted ages for each year
    children_population.append(children[children["year"] == year]["population"].sum())
```

Which NumPy and Pandas tools suits me?